# Symfony2 create own encoder for storing password

Tags: php, security, symfony, hash

I'm new to Symfony2 and I have maybe a simple question about encoding my user passwords in my DB.

I'd like to encode and store in DB my users' password that way:

```
encoded_password = salt . sha1 ( salt . raw_password )
```

I've found various encoders (sha1, sha512, plaintext), I saw that with plaintext I have in my DB raw_password{salt} but I'm still not comfortable with signin/login/getSalt() method in Symfony2.

If you could give me a lift on that (please, assume I do not want to use an existing bundle for UserManagement, I'd like to make my own) it would be AWESOME!

Thanks

EDIT:

I could do that in my signinAction():

```
$salt = substr(md5(time()),0,10);
$pwd = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $salt);
$user->setPassword($salt.$pwd);
```

I could do that in my getSalt():

```
return substr($this->password,0,10);
```

But I currently have only that in my loginAction(): (see here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

```
// src/Acme/SecurityBundle/Controller/Main;
namespace Acme\SecurityBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render('AcmeSecurityBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
}
```

How can I tell Symfony2 to check the password during the login action the way I need? (curently doing encode(password,salt) and not salt.encode(password,salt)

Comment: *"I'm still not comfortable with signin/login/getSalt() method in Symfony2"* - about what specifically? Would be good to know to answer your question.

Comment: That means that I see how to implement this behaviour on my Signin Controller, but I currently use the Sf2 default loginAction and do not know how to implement it in that one.

Comment: To which bundle are you referring to?

Comment: Hey @hakre, I put some code in my question. Hope it will help you to understand my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out my bundle: https://github.com/elnur/ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle. It provides real encryption — not just hashing.

Comment: @elnur: I've seen your bundle. Great one. But I'm just not looking for that ;) I'm more focused to keep my old hashs for my users when migrating my solution rather to improve the encryption ;) Thx

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To make it simple: you have to create and add a new [Service](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html), add it to your bundle and specity that the `User` class will use it. First you have to implement your **own password encoder**:

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class Sha256Salted implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{

    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
    {
        return hash('sha256', $salt . $raw); // Custom function for password encrypt
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
    {
        return $encoded === $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt);
    }

}
```

Then you'll add the **service definition** and you want to specify to **use your custom encoder** for the class `User`. In *TestBundle/Resources/config/services.yml* you add custom encoder:

```
services:
    sha256salted_encoder:
        class: Acme\TestBundle\Service\Sha256Salted
```

and in *app/config/security.yml* you can therefore specify your custom class as default encoder (for `Acme\TestBundle\Entity\User` class):

```
 encoders:
   Acme\TestBundle\Entity\User:
     id: acme.test.sha256salted_encoder
```

Of course, salt plays a central role in password encryption. Salt is unique and is stored for each user. The class `User` can be auto-generated using YAML annotations (table should - of course - contain fields username, password, salt and so on) and should implement `UserInterface`.

Finally you can use it (controller code) when you have to create a new `Acme\TestBundle\Entity\User`:

```
// Add a new User
$user = new User();
$user->setUsername = 'username';
$user->setSalt(uniqid(mt_rand())); // Unique salt for user

// Set encrypted password
$encoder = $this->container->get('acme.test.sha256salted_encoder')
  ->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword('MyPass', $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($password);
```

Comment: Perfect!! You made my day! I was desperate loosing all my passwords during migration between my old solution and the new one using sf2 ;)

Comment: Hi, this works perfect to create a account. But how can I use to login my user?

Comment: Because the user is not going to be authenticated. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you gremo, There's a small problem in the last snippet of your code, when using the service we should put it's name "sha256salted_encoder" and not acme.test.sha256salted_encoder.
in addition

```
// Add a new User
$user = new User();
$user->setUsername = 'username';
$user->setSalt(uniqid(mt_rand())); // Unique salt for user

// Set encrypted password
$encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')
  ->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword('MyPass', $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($password);
```

first of all we will call the security encoder, then we will find

> sha256salted_encoder

and the service will be useful.

All the best

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you should / must only use the bcrypt encoder to safely store password into your database.

here is why:

http://dustwell.com/how-to-handle-passwords-bcrypt.html

http://adambard.com/blog/3-wrong-ways-to-store-a-password/

To configure this encoder you should edit your security.yml file

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface: bcrypt
```

This encoder is used inside the `UserPasswordEncoder` class which can be found here: `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder`