# How should you validate input to a password setter?

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I've been looking at my options for Symfony2 validation.  The problem is this:

I have a Member class that hashes a password in the setPassword method:

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = Encrypt::cryptPassword($password);
}
```

The hash is a long string that exists regardless of the original input.

For this reason validation like this is useless:

```
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = "8",
 *      max = "15",
 *      minMessage = "Your password must be at least {{ limit }} characters",
 *      maxMessage = "Your password cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
 * )
```

The validation is triggered because the hash string is created regardless of the validity of the input.

I looked at trying a getter validation, but this also seems to be a dead end, because again, what I really want to validate is the original input to setPassword() and getting the hash value after setPassword has created a hash value isn't helpful.

What's the recommended approach to this that works with the existing Validation component that will let me validate the original user input?

**Update**

> Although I accepted the answer, it is not really viable.  It did cause
>   me to focus in on the lifecycle callback system which will probably be
>   part of the solution.
>
> Given the current suggestion,  once the password is encoded the first
>   time, validation is exceeded anytime you try and edit the entity
>   because the hashed password is of course not the input and cannot be
>   decrypted into the original input.
>
> I'm experimenting now with a separate attribute in the entity, purely
>   for the entry of the password, along with the use of validation groups
>   to trigger the use of validation in certain circumstances (new user
>   creation/ password change) while omitting it in other cases.  I do
>   plan to make use of the prePersist and preUpdate callbacks to do the
>   encoding of the password.
>
> Just for the record, this is being employed in an application that
>   provides a REST api, as well as administration tools and a web front
>   end for selected functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use doctrine [lifecycles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks) and never modify the behavior of a setter !

```
<?php

// ...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Member
{
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     *
     * First time you save the entity
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->password = Encrypt::cryptPassword($this->password);
    }
}
```

In this example, password is not encoded until you save your member object, so it can be validate by an assert !

However Symfony2 security comes with a firewall that can encrypt the password of members and simply do the job for you:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password

Comment: Sybio is right, you should use the Symfony2 security component. It is highly configurable and lets you define your own password encoder which is invoked when you save your user. So during validation you'll have plain passwords (which Symfony won't store in the session) and can use your assertions withouth problems.

Comment: @Sybio: this looks promising, will give it a spin, and follow up.

Comment: This is not really a viable answer, because unfortunately, once the password is encoded, the validation is exceeded afterwards.  I'm experimenting now with a seperate attribute in entity purely for the entry of the password.

Comment: @Sybio: I assume that your prePersist needs to be:  $this->password = Encrypt::cryptPassword($this->password);

Comment: @gview Corrected ! But I highly recommend to use the security component that comes with sf2, if you want to respect the philosophy of the framework ! If you want to use your own encrypt algorithm because of special needs, you can create your own password encoder and use it in the security component. Here some example how to proceed: http://blogsh.de/2011/09/29/create-a-custom-password-encoder-for-symfony/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878887/symfony2-create-own-encoder-for-storing-password/8175657#8175657

Comment: @Sybio:  I am using the password encoder in the web app version of the system.  I don't actually see how that is relevant to the question though.  Unless I misunderstand this, I'd have have to move the validation for password only into the controllers which was what I was hoping to avoid.