# How to convert sha1() passwords into FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have legacy application that keeps passwords encrypted with `sha1()` function, no salt.

Now that site is being converted into Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle, how can I transfer them to new database?

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem

just override the encoder like explained by @iamdto

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: 
           id: your.custom.encoder
```

Your class should be

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class CustomEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{

    public function encodePassword( $raw, $salt ) {
        //do not use salt here
        return sha1($raw);
    }

    public function isPasswordValid( $encoded, $raw, $salt ) {
        return $encoded === $this->encodePassword( $raw, $salt );
    }
}
```

You should add a column "version"  to get legacy users and update their infos on next login

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha1
```

You should have a look at these references too :

- [Configure your application's security.yml](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-configure-your-applications-securityyml)
- [Encoding the User's Password](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password)

Comment: That came up to my mind also but it won't work because of the `salt` value required in FOSUserBundle and I don't have it in old code. As per docs, salt is prepended to password. I will try to put empty string in `salt` column (if DB even allows that) but I don't think it is a good solution.

Comment: I just tried what you said and placed empty string in `salt` column; I can't login :(

Comment: In fact this is not the way to go. Not sure you can disable salting by default. In this case I think you should create your own password encoder. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8175657/1337344 for an example on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague wrote a bundle for this very purpose:

https://packagist.org/packages/markup/fallback-password-encoder-bundle

Comment: For anyone else stumbling on this answer. Note that none of the other answers given here will convert your old passwords to a better encryption scheme going forward (eg bcrypt etc.). You should use a secure hashing method for your application and support these older logins as a fallback, rather than sticking with unsalted sha1. That is what the above bundle does.