# Is it possible to re-use sha512 passwords of former site on a new Symfony Project with FOSUser Bundle?

Tags: symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

I'm currently working with Symfony3 on a new version of an old site. That site has members with sha512-encrypted passwords (and no salt). My new project uses FOSUser Bundle, and what I would like is to allow my members to use their former password on the new web site. Of course, a simple copy/paste in the new DB doesn't work, as FOSUser uses $salt when a new member registers. 
So is there a way to achieve that somehow ? Or do I have to make en extra step for the current members to transform their password ? I'm quite a beginner with Symfony so I would really appreciate some help or advice.
Thank you, and have a nice day :)

Comment: Have you tried to override `getSalt()` method of your User to return empty string? I found it here - https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/946. If it works correctly then you will be able to use old passwords without salt.

Comment: I tried that method [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435820/how-to-convert-sha1-passwords-into-fosuserbundle?rq=1) which should have done the same, but now I have a "Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem." Thanks FOSBundle for that explicit error message ^^

Comment: This post is 4 years old, so he can use FOSUserBundle version 1 instead of 2 (I don't know what version are you using). This this might be a case. Try the getSalt() maybe.

Comment: I just tried ; same error. Could it be possible to override the loginAction of FOSUSERBundle to make him check if there is a $oldPassword in DB, then automatically create a new user ?

Comment: You can http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html but I think you need to overwrite LoginManager as long as there is checking password correctness