# How to use the Password Encoder from Drupal 7 in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, drupal-7, symfony-2.1

I would like to use my drupal database to authenticate the users on my symfony application. I should be able to retrieve their encoded passwords to compare it with the submitted ones. The problem is that I don't think the basic encoders are used in Drupal component (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21password.inc/function/_password_crypt/7).

Thus, my question is, how can I implement drupal encoder in symfony custom encoder?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7

Then following the function calls, you should be able to mimic this is Symfony. It's basically using sha512 with a salt.

See this question for how to code your own encoder in Symfony: [Symfony2 create own encoder for storing password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878887/symfony2-create-own-encoder-for-storing-password)

Comment: Thanks, actually I have done it, and my password was working only if there were no hash sign. Now, I am trying to include the drupal bootstrap and use the function as it is. Afterwards, I will try to mimic the function to avoid loading all the included library.