# Symfony2 custom algorithm password encoder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I want to use a custom algorithm for encoding user passwords (custom password encoder), any way to do that? I am using symfony 2.6.6 with FOSUserBundle 2.dev.

More detail: I have an app to develop but in my case the table of users already exists (the whole database exists) password column is encoded using a custom algorithm written in Java, in order to use FOSUserBundle I have to use this same algorithm (written in PHP) to encode passwords. How exactly can I do this in Symfony?

Comment: What custom algorithm do you want to use specifically? What have you tried in furtherance of this aim?

Comment: ok, so i have an app to develop but in my case the table of users already exists( the whole db exists) password column is encoded using a custom algorithm written in java , in order to use FOSUserBundle I have to use this same algo (written in php)to encode passwords how exactly can i do this in symfony 2

Comment: But the kind of algorithm (Bcrypt, Sha512, etc) used by the Java program is secret?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878887/symfony2-create-own-encoder-for-storing-password