# Decrypt python/django password with Symfony 2.5 (using symfony security)

Tags: php, python, django, symfony, encryption

I want to use symfony 2.5.10 security in order to login in from users that were created with pyhton/django security. Passwords in db that are encrypted in this format:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$12000$dVPTWPll8poG$3weiWwv4P/2GgYjeJBeUN/Hlbe1UByCj7ZRVX93FBZE=
```

I want to do this because I want users to have same passwords for the new app.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write password encoder on your own. Django uses following password format:

```
<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
```

It means hash uses the PBKDF2 algorithm with a SHA256 hash, 12000 iterations, `dVPTWPll8poG` salt (for this particular password) and password hash itself is `3weiWwv4P/2GgYjeJBeUN/Hlbe1UByCj7ZRVX93FBZE=` (BASE64 encoded).

Symfony has password encoder for PBKDF2 but it does not support Django format. You can just modify built-in password encoder. You have to extract iterations, salt and pbkdf hash from string in database. The rest is the same as in default encoder.

https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/2.5/Encoder/Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.php

Here is another stackoverflow answer on how to write own password encoder.

[Symfony2 create own encoder for storing password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878887/symfony2-create-own-encoder-for-storing-password)

Hope that's help.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's the time to give this a try.

Comment: What is the format of the symfony's built in password encoder? In what format to store the django password?

Answer (score 0):

Django uses hashing to store user passwords. Depending on your `settings.PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting it will use one of [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/hashers/) functions.

You will have to port same hashing algorithm in php