# Migrate passwords from Django to Symfony 3

Tags: django, symfony, encryption, passwords

Our client requested to change technology used in a product, from Django to Symfony3. Now, when all work is done, we need to transfer all production users from Django to Symfony. Everything is done except password migration. I'm not sure on how to achieve this. The article that I found says what should be done, but im not sure how to do it.

This is the url I found that has some information on it:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387626/decrypt-python-django-password-with-symfony-2-5-using-symfony-security?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But im not sure how to implement it. Anybody who knows more on this or who has actually done it?

Comment: How many users are we talking about here?

Comment: @dfundako around 100

Comment: Just use the same algo and hashing method in symfony and simply copy password hashes to the symfony db. As far as I understand django by default uses PBKDF2 + SHA256, symfony supports it - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html